# Android - API Request Callback after onDestroy

Tags: android, callback, android-volley, android-lifecycle, ondestroy

I hope I can explain this well ...

I am trying to understand better how to handle HTTP callbacks in Android, so I have created a simple app that uses Volley for HTTP requests. It only has a button that triggers an HTTP request to a service that, basically, just updates a number in a database and sends it in the JSON response after 5 seconds. The Activity gets the response and displays the response in a TextView. I am testing it in a real device that has enabled the "Don't keep activities" option in Settings - Developer Options.

This is the scenario I am testing:

1. Start App.
2. Tap the button that triggers the HTTP request.
3. Inmediately after tapping the button, tap the device's home button to send the app to background. onDestroy method is called because of the "Don't keep activities" option.
4. Wait a few seconds for the HTTP response. I can see the device gets it because it is printed in the logcat monitor and the database is updated.
5. Before running the callback, I check that the activity is still alive. Since the activity has been destroyed, the callback is ignored. If the app is restored from background, there is no crash but the Network Response is missed. Also, if I tap the button again, it sends a new HTTP request and increases the number again ...

So, the questions are:

1. Which are the best practices to deliver network responses to the UI? I mean, if instead of a simple operation let's say it was a register form and I get a phone call or something that forces me to send the app to background, where anything can happens, how can I make sure to not miss the network callback? Is there something that could delay the callback execution until the app is again in foreground?
2. Is there a way to save a Bundle like the one in onSaveInstanceState after onDestroy has been called and restore it when app is again in foreground?
3. Let's say the information that the HTTP response contains is sensitive. Is there a recommended way to handle this case? I was thinking to save the response in the internal storage and check for it when the app is again in foreground, but I don't know if it is possible to do that after onDestroy has been called, or if it not a good idea with sensitive data.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

1)YOu can never miss the network callback.  You'll be called even if you're in the background, unless your entire app (not just the activity is killed).  You'll just get the callback while backgrounded.

2)No.  If you need the result of a network call the next time the activity starts like that, I suggest you use a Loader to load the data.  That way you can query for the Loader results next time, and start the request only if needed.

3)Do what I suggested in 2 and there's no need for this question, its all in app memory.

Comment: Hi @Gabe ... 1. By "not miss the callback" I meant to not miss the execution of that block. I am, in fact, getting the callback but I can not use it to update my UI because it has been destroyed. 2 & 3. Thanks, I will try with the Loader. By any chance, do you have any example?

Comment: Loader also fixes that problem

Comment: I am trying to combine Loaders with MVP. I have read some articles that encourage to use Loaders to retain the Presenters, but I also send a Volley request from my presenter (to log in a user, per example) and I have the same problem as before: the callback can be delivered to the presenter when the view (Activity, Fragment) is not in the foreground. I thought of using a Loader inside the Presenter, but it seems not a good idea because the Presenter should avoid android imports. Do you know or have an idea how to manage this situation?